# If row colum contains a value, multiply and add up

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ea9pExb.png]

I need to build an excel program which checks if co-workers manage to do their task. Every worker (specified as *person* in the sheet) gets assigned a number of groups, and how much tasks in each group. For example, Person 1 here needs to do 20 tasks in group 1 and 55 in group 3. But since group 3 is fairly easy, I have given this group a high factor, meaning that for example he has to do more of group 3 than group 1.

To calculate how much Person 1 now has done, I want to multiply everything in column B with the group factor in column F. For example, for Person 1 I need to calculate `(20 * 0.5) + (55 * 1,5)`.

So underneath the groups, I have this function:

`= SOM(B3:B5 * F3:F5)`

Sadly, this doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: try `=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B5,F3:F5)` or use it as an arrayformula `=SUM(B3:B5*F3:F5)` with Ctr+Shift+Enter

Comment: Sumproduct did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Just to put my comment-solution into an answer:

try `=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B5,F3:F5)`
or use it as an array formula `=SUM(B3:B5*F3:F5)` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>